# Transform Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame that looks like this

```
     exec       ms        tp    lu    ru
0   exec1     16.0    240.87  2.30  0.85
1   exec1     16.0    243.72  2.35  0.84
2   exec1     16.0    234.16  2.38  0.92
3   exec1     16.0    244.71  2.35  0.84
4   exec1     16.0    240.74  2.39  0.90
5   exec1    128.0   1686.78  2.09  0.69
6   exec1    128.0   1704.36  2.00  0.44
7   exec1    128.0   1686.45  2.07  0.60
8   exec1    128.0   1722.61  2.07  0.45
9   exec1    128.0   1726.15  2.08  0.50
10  exec1   1024.0   5754.92  2.23  0.93
11  exec1   1024.0   5740.71  2.24  0.93
12  exec1   1024.0   5751.58  2.24  0.96
13  exec1   1024.0   5819.63  2.23  0.92
14  exec1   1024.0   5797.03  2.22  0.96
15  exec1   8192.0  37833.45  1.91  3.87
16  exec1   8192.0  38154.95  2.00  3.87
17  exec1   8192.0  38178.19  2.02  3.85
18  exec1   8192.0  38152.86  1.95  3.84
19  exec1   8192.0  35209.98  1.80  3.65
20  exec1  16384.0  38109.76  1.81  3.84
21  exec1  16384.0  38059.07  1.76  3.90
22  exec1  16384.0  36683.24  1.54  3.71
23  exec1  16384.0  37908.00  1.73  3.85
24  exec1  16384.0  37014.79  1.71  3.75
```

and I would like to make columns from *ms* for data from *tp*, *lu* and *ru* and have them as hierarchical columns and use *exec* as the index like this:

```
                                               lu                                          ru                                         tp
exec    16.0    128.0   1024.0  8192.0  16384.0     16.0    128.0   1024.0  8192.0  16384.0     16.0    128.0   1024.0  8192.0  16384.0
exec1   2.30    2.09    2.23    1.91    1.81    0.85    0.69    0.93    3.87    3.84    240.87  1686.78     5754.92     37833.45    38109.76
exec1   2.35    2.00    2.24    2.00    1.76    0.84    0.44    0.93    3.87    3.90    243.72  1704.36     5740.71     38154.95    38059.07
exec1   2.38    2.07    2.24    2.02    1.54    0.92    0.60    0.96    3.85    3.71    234.16  1686.45     5751.58     38178.19    36683.24
exec1   2.35    2.07    2.23    1.95    1.73    0.84    0.45    0.92    3.84    3.85    244.71  1722.61     5819.63     38152.86    37908.00
exec1   2.39    2.08    2.22    1.80    1.71    0.90    0.50    0.96    3.65    3.75    240.74  1726.15     5797.03     35209.98    37014.79
```

I tried using pd.pivot_table but it creates unwanted *nans*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May need `groupby` +`cumcount` create a additional key , then do `pivot` transform , here I am using `unstack` , if you need check [pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe) , personally think this explain better than the official document

```
df.assign(key=df.groupby(['exec','ms']).cumcount()).set_index(['exec','ms','key']).unstack([1])
```